# How do I figure out what the error is when using Rails 3.2 to do a rake test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am starting to think its the version of ruby I am using ruby-1.9.3-p125 or maybe the gems its hard to tell when your new. I was building a shopping cart app from the book Agile Web Development with Rails 4th edition. If there is anyway who can help I would appreciate at that thank you

```
new-host:depot Tony$ rake test:units
/Users/Tony/work/depot/test/unit/product_test.rb:1:in `test': wrong number of arguments (1 for 2) (ArgumentError)
    from /Users/Tony/work/depot/test/unit/product_test.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Tony/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activesupport-3.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /Users/Tony/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activesupport-3.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
    from /Users/Tony/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activesupport-3.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/Tony/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activesupport-3.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /Users/Tony/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:10:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
    from /Users/Tony/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:9:in `each'
    from /Users/Tony/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:9:in `block in <main>'
    from /Users/Tony/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:4:in `select'
    from /Users/Tony/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:4:in `<main>'
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [/Users/Tony/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125...]
```

Comment: try prefixing with `bundle exec` to make sure only relevant gems get loaded

Comment: Can you post the first few lines of your product_test.rb file?  It is indicating there is a problem right in the top of that file.

Comment: Yeah but I can't do that till around 10:30pm.

Comment: test "product price must be positive" do
  product = Product.new(title: "My Book Title",
                        description: "yyy",
                        image_url: "zzz.jpg")
  product.price = -1
  assert product.invalid?
  assert_equal "must be greater than or equal to 0.01",
     product.errors[:price].join('; ')
  product.price = 0
  assert product.invalid?
  assert_equal "must be greater than or equal to 0.01",
     product.errors[:price].join('; ')
  product.price = 1
  assert product.valid?
end

Comment: I got this out of the Agile Web Development with Rais 4th Edition book.

Answer (score 1):

I was dealing for hours with the same error, hope this helps

Your test/unit/product_test.rb should look like this

```
class PostTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
    test "product attributes must not be empty" do
      product = Product.new
      assert product.invalid?
      assert product.errors[:title].any?
      assert product.errors[:description].any?
      assert product.errors[:price].any?
      assert product.errors[:image_url].any?
    end
end
```